# How can I call the Agora API from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser?

Tags: angular7, agora.io

When I call Agora API for getting the live channel name from PostMan tool then it is successfully called but the problem is that when I try to call Agora API using Angular7, then it gives me cross-origin with 404 error. I have mentioned exception below.

```
OPTIONS https://api.agora.io/dev/v1/channel/{App Id}/ 404 (Not Found)



Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.agora.io/dev/v1/channel/{App Id}/' from origin MY IP has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

Agora's REST API is meant to be invoked from the server side. The credentials used in the API are sensitive and are not meant to be exposed on the client side. This is why the API throws a CORS when you try to use it on the browser.

Use any sever-side language(Node JS, Python, Go etc.) to query the API.

Comment: How video and audio will stream from server side?